# How could I get elements of DOM in ANGULAR to store in a variable?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've made with ANGULAR (5.2.3) a code which gives me a huge table:

```
<table #ref id="table" ...>
....
</table>
```

I would like to get the source code of this table to show in a textarea.

First, I created a function to retrieve this.ref, but I got [HTMLTableElement] as return, not the source code.

After that I've changed the code to build the table inside the controller, what seems wrong and hard to maintain the code because mix the template and the data.

I tried even with pure javascript with getElementById(), innerHTML, etc, but I'm missing something.

I know how to do it with JQuery, but I don't want to use JQuery just for that.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `HTMLTableElement` means you get the element ref of table , what else do you need ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? `HTMLTableElement` is the equivalent of what you would recieve from `getElementById()`

Comment: I need the entire code, table, tr, td, content, etc. This code it's what's matter for the user.

Comment: Try this `document.getElementById("table").outerHTML`

Comment: Thanks hrdkisback! Works perfectly!